# The best pattern for change language in a website

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

i'm making a complex website that needs to be multi-language (including right-to-left languages).

Particularities of the problem:

- It's a MVC website with only two pages.
- This pages have a lot of fields that needs to be translate.
- Needs to be in real-time change (i don't wanna reload the page to make the translation).

The problem:
My problem is if i should have key/value pair for every field i have in page or if i have a key/value par for every expression. 
I'm asking because I didn't this before and i don't know what solutions is more used.

**Example:**

Field1 = Happy day!

Field2 = Happy day!

**Solved with first solution:**

Field1 = "Happy day!"

Field2 = "Happy day!"

Field1 = HappyDay

Field2 = HappyDay

**Solved with second solution:**

HappyDay = Happy day!

Field1 = HappyDay

Field2 = HappyDay

Comment: I know that you don't want to reload the page, but you can check the location before the load, so you will be able to set the language.

Comment: The term you should be looking for is **internationalization**. I've heard i18next can help with this - https://github.com/i18next/i18next. If it needs to be a real-time change, you'll have to use geolocation api of HTML5 to detect the location and using that the language.

Comment: @Pablo I'm using ajax + "TR_<fieldname>" class name in each field that i need to translate. My problem which pattern should i use, the first solution or the second solution (take in count performance and maintenance)

Comment: @amulous Thank you for share i18next library. The problem was that i already started make the language core of my application :S Maybe in next time use i18next. Now i'm looking for the best solution for the specific problem that i expose in this question. The problem of choose between "field translation" or "expression translation".